# Correct usage of "Denn" in this text? (location of verb)

Tags: verb, conjunction

> Diese Perspektive ermöglicht es auch, die Formen und Folgen der Computerisierung von »Systemen der Sicherheit« vergleichend zu untersuchen, und, wie es hier geschehen soll, DDR-Staatssicherheit und das Bundeskriminalamt bzw. die westdeutsche Polizei. **Denn so unterschiedlich die Rahmenbedingungen und Ziele dieser Behörden auch waren** – sie standen in den 1960er-Jahren vor vergleichbaren Herausforderungen: Sie mussten einer »Informationsflut« Herr werden, also ihre Kapazitäten zur Informationsverarbeitung erhöhen,
>   und sich dem gesellschaftlichen und soziotechnischen Wandel anpassen.

Sorry for this long quote. I thought that I need to provide the proper context with my question, which is: WHY is the author locating the verb "waren" at the end of the phrase of "Denn"? As my grammar knowledge, it should go like "Denn waren die Rahmenbedigungen und Ziele dieser Behörden auch so unterschiedlich ~."

I would appreciate if somebody help my understanding. :)

Comment: The position of "waren" and the usage of "denn" are two different issues. Actually "denn" could be omitted here without changing the rest of the sentence. The important word is "so".

Comment: No problem with long quotes; it is more annoying having to ask for more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Denn* is not the important word here. What we have here is the concessive use of "so".

Example from Duden["so"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_obwohl_falls), meaning 3:

> So leid es mir tut, ich muss absagen.

For the first part introduced by *so*, verb-last order applies.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding the sentence in question lies in recognising the fact that

> **so unterschiedlich** die Rahmenbedingungen und Ziele dieser Behörden auch **waren**

is a verb-final subordinate clause at the left periphery of the sentence (*linkes Außenfeld*; [Feldermodell](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/2020)). The subordinate clause can be moved around, showing that the order of *denn* – subject – verb is as expected.

> Denn diese Behörden standen in den 1960er-Jahren, *so unterschiedlich ihre Rahmenbedingungen und Ziele auch waren*, vor vergleichbaren Herausforderungen.
>
> Denn diese Behörden standen in den 1960er-Jahren vor vergleichbaren Herausforderungen,  *so unterschiedlich ihre Rahmenbedingungen und Ziele auch waren*.

Subordinate clauses of this kind are introduced by *so* + adjective and usually contain *auch*.

> **So sehr** sie es **auch versuchte**, sie  konnte sich nicht erinnern.
> *Try as she might* / *no matter how hard she tried*, *she could not remember*.

The current term for the meaning of these types of clauses is *irrelevanzkonditional* ([Wörterbuch der Konnektoren](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/konnektoren/406898)). With regard to the given example, the idea is that the degree of trying is irrelevant for the truth of the main clause proposition, i.e. her not remembering.

There are many constructions with similar meaning.

> *Wie sehr er auch bat*, so verzieh sie ihm doch nicht.
>
> Seine grobe Ausdrucksweise wurde sein Markenzeichen und traf jeden, der ihm in die Quere kam, *mochte er auch noch so hochgestellt sein*.
>
> *Ob du es glaubst oder nicht*, du bist die erste Person, der ich das erzähle.